# Type of bit-field members

Tags: c++, c, bit-fields

Theoretically, we have two options to chose the type of a bit field member:

1. The type of the underlying type.
2. The smallest type the number of bits fits in.

So what is the actually the type of bit-field members (I couldn't find so far hints in the standard – C and C++ alike) and is there any difference in between C and C++?

Although being aware that a specific compiler is not the reference, I tried to get at least some hints via C++ function overloads and typeid operator :

```
#include <typeinfo>
struct S
{
    unsigned int n4  :  4;
    unsigned int n12 : 12;
};

void f(unsigned char)
{
    std::cout << "uc" << std::endl;
}

void f(unsigned short)
{
    std::cout << "us" << std::endl;
}

void f(unsigned int)
{
    std::cout << "ui" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    S s; s.n4 = 0; s.n12 = 0;
    f(s.n4);
    f(s.n12);
    std::cout << typeid(s.n4).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(s.n12).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(unsigned char).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(unsigned short).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(unsigned int).name() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output (GCC 5.4.0 under linux) was totally surprising and – in my eyes at least – contradicting:

```
ui
ui
h
t
h
t
j
```

So if type, according to typeid operator, is unsigned char and unsigned short respectively, why is unsigned int selected during overload resolution? Possibly even a GCC bug?

Addendum: GCC 8.1 (linux) still exhibits the same behaviour.

Comment: Visual C++ will display `ui` as expected and also `unsigned int` for the names of `s.n4` and  `s.n12`. I would think that either VC++ is right for `typeid().name()` or it is unspecified.

Comment: Clang [agrees with MSVC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MzT9UHUsuIZArlia).  Does seem to be a GCC bug: why would `unsigned int` declare something to be of some *other* type?

Comment: @DavisHerring Well, it's not unsigned int - if it was, it would be legal to apply `sizeof` and that would yield 4 (typically, at least). Just yielding the underlying type results in simpler rules, an argument, but not a definitive answer. A bitfield member with 8 bits being of type `(u)int8_t` (no matter what the underlying type actually is) does not appear totally illogical either, at least not enough to prevent the apparent GCC bug (where printing `uc us` instead would *possibly* yet have been acceptable, not, though, showing the inconsistent behaviour).

Comment: @Aconcagua: There’s no contradiction: remember that bit-field-ness, like value category, is an *additional* property of an expression beyond its type.  `sizeof` [specifically checks and rejects](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#1) that property in its argument.

Comment: @DavisHerring "additional property" - finally the decisive hint... Continuing the thought, then we *first* assign the type to a bit field member and tell *afterwards* how many bits we actually use... Do you have the appropriate section of the standard available backing this consideration?

Comment: @Aconcagua: Do you mean something other than just [\[class.bit\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.bit)?

Comment: @DavisHerring No, it's exactly what I was asking about... Must have overlooked the decisive phrase when searching the standard before posting the question, in your link, I discovered it, though... If you post an answer yourself, I'll accept it instead of mine - it's you to deserve the reputation...

Comment: @Aconcagua: I said nothing worthy: the reputation should go to whomever files (or finds) the GCC bug.

Comment: @DavisHerring Your hint about bitfieldness and the link led me to the solution... Bug is now [official](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87547).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [C++ standard § 10.3.10.1 (class.bit)](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.bit):

> The bit-field attribute is not part of the type of the class member.

(I must have overlooked this phrase from the standard when posting the question...)

So the standard is clear about the type of a bit-field member, it is equal to the underlying type.

Thanks to [Davis Herring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8586227/davis-herring) for giving me the appropriate hints.